# Yarn start met with [HPM] Missing "target" option. Example: {target: "http://www.example.org"}

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, cra

I cloned a CRA repo and switched from npm to yarn. after running yarn start I am met with an error that says

```
[HPM] Missing "target" option. Example: {target: "http://www.example.org"}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Can't seem to find much info about a fix online

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

The problem was that some of the **components** were trying to access **environment variables** that did not exist.
If this is the case, make sure that the `.env` file is present in **the root of the project** with the **environment variables well defined**.

For example:

```
// .env

REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL = http://localhost:3001
```